# tuple index out of range как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание:

Напишите функцию `concat`, которая будет принимать произвольное число строк и объединять их в одну через разделитель (sep). Если разделитель не задан, то она будет объединять их через пробел.

Код:

```py
def concat(*string):
    if string[-2] == '=':
        sep = string[-1]
        return sep.join(string)
    return ' '.join(string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Странный код:

- Непонятные операции с `if string[-2] == '=':`
- Отсутствие разделителя в параметре самой функции

Можно проще:

```
def concat(*string, sep=' '):
    return sep.join(string)
```

Тест:

```
>>> concat('a', 'b', 'c')
'a b c'

>>> concat('a', 'b', 'c', sep='=')
'a=b=c'

>>> items = ('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> concat(*items)
'a b c'
```

Answer (score 0):

C `map()` для преобразования в строку, полезно  для вызова функции с числами:

```
def concat(*string, sep=' '):
    return sep.join(map(str, string))
```